# Getting only specific group line breaks in proc report

Tags: sas, report

I'm trying to format my table using proc format but cannot figure out quite how to specify line breaks for only a specific group in my data.

Have

[image: Have output]

Want

[image: Want output]

This is currently how my data is structured:

[image: Data Structure]

Here is the code I've been stuck trying to figure out...

```
title "Table 1";
options orientation = landscape nonumber nodate leftmargin=0.05in rightmargin=0.05in;
ods noproctitle noresults escapechar='^';
ods rtf  file = "path";

 proc report data= work.appendix_a1  nowd spanrows 
    style(header)=[vjust=b font_face = Calibri fontsize=9pt font_weight=bold background=&blue. foreground=white borderrightcolor=black];
    /*List variables in order to select order of columns in table*/
    col ( m_type1
          ('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. vjust=b borderbottomwidth=0.02 }Table'('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. vjust=b borderbottomwidth=0.02 }Characteristics' m_char_desc)) 
          ('^S={cellheight=0.20in}CY 2016' 
          ('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. borderbottomwidth=0.02 cellheight=0.18in}' count_16) 
          ('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. borderbottomwidth=0.02 cellheight=0.18in}' percentage_16))
          ('^S={cellheight=0.20in}CY2017' 
          ('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. borderbottomwidth=0.02 cellheight=0.18in}' count_17)
          ('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. borderbottomwidth=0.02 cellheight=0.18in}' percentage_17))
          ('^S={cellheight=0.20in}CY2018' 
          ('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. borderbottomwidth=0.02 cellheight=0.18in}' count_18)
          ('^S={borderbottomcolor=&blue. borderbottomwidth=0.02 cellheight=0.18in}' percentage_18)));

define m_type1 /order=data group noprint;

        define m_char_desc / order=data display  style = [vjust=m just=center cellwidth=0.90in font_face='Times New Roman' fontsize=8pt]
                         '' style(header)=[vjust=t just=left cellheight=0.05in] ;
        define count_16      /display style = [vjust=m just=center  cellwidth=0.45in cellheight=0.05in font_face='Times New Roman' fontsize=9pt] 
                         'n' style(header)=[vjust=t just=center cellheight=0.18in];
        define percentage_16  /display style = [vjust=m just=center  cellwidth=0.45in cellheight=0.05in font_face='Times New Roman' fontsize=9pt] 
                         '%' style(header)=[vjust=t just=center cellheight=0.18in];
        define count_17 /display style = [vjust=m just=center  cellwidth=0.45in cellheight=0.05in font_face='Times New Roman' fontsize=9pt] 
                         'n' style(header)=[vjust=t just=center cellheight=0.18in];
        define percentage_17  /display style = [vjust=m just=center  cellwidth=0.45in cellheight=0.05in font_face='Times New Roman' fontsize=9pt] 
                         '%' style(header)=[vjust=t just=center cellheight=0.18in];
        define count_18      /display style = [vjust=m just=center  cellwidth=0.45in cellheight=0.05in font_face='Times New Roman' fontsize=9pt] 
                         'n' style(header)=[vjust=t just=center cellheight=0.18in];
        define percentage_18  /display style = [vjust=m just=center  cellwidth=0.45in cellheight=0.05in font_face='Times New Roman' fontsize=9pt] 
                         '%' style(header)=[vjust=t just=center cellheight=0.18in];


compute before m_type1/
style=Header{just=l fontweight=bold fontsize=8pt};
length brkline $100;
brkline = catx('',m_type1);
line brkline $varying100.;
endcomp;

run;

ods rtf close;
```

Comment: Why does the title say `in Proc FORMAT` ?  Is the question really "how to set the entire row to be bold for only certain groups" in `Proc REPORT` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This modifies the other answer to produce the desired result using $VARYING format.

SAS Usage note on the subject: http://support.sas.com/kb/37/763.html

```
proc report data=sashelp.cars;
  where type = 'Sedan' and drivetrain = 'All' and msrp < 30000; 
  title "All wheel Sedans under $30K";
  columns origin make model msrp;
  define origin / order noprint;

  compute before origin 
  / style = [
      fontweight=bold 
      background=lightgray 
      textalign=left 
      cellpadding=111pt
    ]
  ;
    length linetext $200.;
    linetext = origin;
    if origin='Asia' then l=0;
    else l=length(linetext);
    line linetext $varying200. l;
  endcomp;

  compute origin;    
    if not missing(origin) then
      hold_origin = origin;

    if hold_origin = 'Asia' then
      call define (_row_, 'style', 'style=[fontweight=bold background=VLIG fontstyle=italic]');

  endcomp;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem but $VARYING needs a length variable.

```
line brkline $varying100. LENGTHVARIABLE;
```

To remove TOTAL line set length variable to 0;

Comment: I'm confused by your comment. Do you mean format or set?

Comment: Your LINE statement was missing the mandatory second variable that the $VARYING format  needs.  That variable controls how many characters the format actually writes. The width number in the format specification is just the MAX number of characters that will be written.  If the second variable (the numeric variable with the number of characters to write) is zero then no characters are written.

Answer (score 0):

**LINE Statement**

Regardless of 'logic' that appears to constrain `LINE`, you can't conditionally issue a line statement (thus somehow preventing the TOTAL summary line).

From the docs:

> **[LINE Statement](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n0hkzudub5hfm5n171w4fiwhtxv8.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)**
>   Provides a subset of the features of the PUT statement for writing customized summaries.
>
> **Restrictions:**
>   This statement is valid only in a compute block that is associated with a location in the report.
>
> ---
>
> You cannot use the LINE statement in conditional statements (IF-THEN, IF-THEN/ELSE, and SELECT) because it is not executed until PROC REPORT has executed all other statements in the compute block.

**Detail row formatting**

Once you understand that `order` variables only have a value for the first report row in the group you will see that the value has to be tracked. *This is for the case of a group having more than one row (your TOTAL does not)*

- Temporary variables can be used to conditionally track values in a `compute` block for a `noprint` `order` variable.
- `call define (_row_, 'style', 'style=[ … ]');` can be used to conditionally modify report detail row styling.

Example:

```
ods rtf file='report.rtf';
ods escapechar='^';

proc report data=sashelp.cars;
  where type = 'Sedan' and drivetrain = 'All' and msrp < 30000; 
  title "All wheel Sedans under $30K";
  columns origin make model msrp;
  define origin / order noprint;

  compute before origin 
  / style = [
      fontweight=bold 
      background=lightgray 
      textalign=left 
      cellpadding=111pt
    ]
  ;
    length linetext $200.;

    if origin='Asia'
      then linetext = ' ';
      else linetext = origin;

    line linetext $200.;
  endcomp;

  compute origin;    
    if not missing(origin) then
      hold_origin = origin;

    if hold_origin = 'Asia' then
      call define (_row_, 'style', 'style=[fontweight=bold background=VLIG fontstyle=italic]');

  endcomp;
run;
ods rtf close;
```

[image]